# Getting autogenerated keys inserted in PostreSQL with pySpark

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I insert a dataframe in a Postgre's table with a bigserial type primary key so it is autoincremented, then I need to insert data related to this in another table, so I need to know the primary key that has been generated for every row, Is there any way to do this with Spark? 
I have tried to generate the keys myself in spark but this may produce race conditions.
Another option would be inserting every row one by one but would be slower

Comment: _"generate the keys myself in spark ... may produce race conditions"_ > do you really mean "race conditions" or just "performance issues"? and did you try a reinvent-the-wheel approach or a built-in Spark method, cf. https://towardsdatascience.com/adding-sequential-ids-to-a-spark-dataframe-fa0df5566ff6 ?

Comment: can you also post a sample code which you have tried for more clarity